# Accessing my wallet

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I've been mining ether to an address but I don't remember where that address came from. I don't remember if I generated it from my command line or if the address was generated from https://www.myetherwallet.com/#generate-wallet
How can I access my wallet and verify that I have control over it. I know I'll have to remember my password (if I can) but I don't even know where to go to enter my password and validate it is indeed my wallet and that I can send/receive ether from and to it. Thanks.

Comment: You have to try a test transaction, from the same account itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you generated it with MyEtherWallet, then you'll have been prompted to download the keystore file and keep it somewhere safe. (MEW [isn't a web wallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#help) - it doesn't keep anything for you.)

If you generated it on your command line, you'll again have the corresponding keystore file in the [location appropriate for your platform](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/109/52), assuming you didn't [override the default location](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/how-can-i-force-geth-to-create-accounts-in-a-different-keystore).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find the keystore file in my Linux miner's home directory, well a sub directory anyway. So now that I now that I generated it from my command line how can I verify that I have access to the wallet? If I can even remember the password where could I even enter it to verify my access and ownership of the address? Thanks.